How to stringify parameter deploy_access_levels for GitLab API (projects/$REPO_ID/protected_environments) for glab cli?
Execute the following command using glab cli return error as shown below;
glab api projects/$REPO_ID/protected_environments \
-F name=master \
-f deploy_access_levels='[{access_level: 40}]' \
-f approval_rules='[{access_level: 40, required_approvals: 1}]'


{
"error": "deploy_access_levels is invalid, approval_rules is invalid"
}
glab: HTTP 400
API Ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/17.3/ee/api/protected_environments.html#protect-a-single-environment
Expecting the command to be successful and protected_environments record created for the target repo.
The api work when using curl command as shown below;
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST \
     --data '{"name": "master", "deploy_access_levels": [{"access_level": 40}], "approval_rules": [{"access_level": 40, "required_approvals": 1}]}' \
     --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" \
     "https://$GITLAB_HOST/api/v4/projects/$REPO_ID/protected_environments"

Executing the following command resulting in error 500, indicating that the API expecting an array of some data;
glab api projects/$REPO_ID/protected_environments \
-F name=master \
-f deploy_access_levels='[]' \                  
-f approval_rules='[]'                                         

{
  "message": "500 Internal Server Error"
}


glab: 500 Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)
Try with other data format resulting in error as well;
glab api projects/$REPO_ID/protected_environments \
-F name=master \
-f deploy_access_levels='[{"access_level": 40}]' \
-f approval_rules="[{ \"access_level\": 40, \"required_approvals\": 1 }]"


{
"error": "deploy_access_levels is invalid, approval_rules is invalid"
}
glab: HTTP 400
But somehow, the following command work on another API which also have a parameter which required an array of object.
export TEMP_ID=$(glab api projects/$REPO_ID/protected_branches | jq '.[0].push_access_levels[0].id')
glab api projects/$REPO_ID/protected_branches/master -X PATCH -f allowed_to_push="[{\"id\": $TEMP_ID, \"access_level\": 0}]"


API Ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html#update-a-protected-branch
Appreciate if anyone can provide any insights or solution, thanks.
